# Laravel with where like condition in relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have a WorkPackage model with below relationship.

```
public function work_items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(WorkItem::class);
}
```

And WorkPackage has 'title','project_id' columns and work_items has 'title','work_package_id' columns. Now I want to search user typed keyword is matching with title in both table.

Here is my tried function

```
public function getWorkPackageProposals($projectId, $title)
{

    $result['data'] = $this->workPackage->with(['work_items' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%");
    }])
        ->where('project_id', $projectId)
        ->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%")
        ->get();
    return $result;
}
```

but its not working.
Please find the below code for I used to create object of WorkPackage.

```
public function __construct(WorkPackage $workPackage)
{
    $this->workPackage = $workPackage;
    $this->setModel(WorkPackage::class);
    $this->workItemRepository = app(WorkItemRepository::class);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to acheive here ?

Comment: I Have two tables with above relation as per given in question, WorkPackage table has 'title','project_id' and work_items table has 'title','work_package_id' columns. Now I want to search keyword with both table where title column of both table will match.

Answer (score 1):

`whereHas()` works to specify additional filters for the related model to check :

```
$result['data'] = $this->workPackage->whereHas('work_items', function ($query) use ($title) {
        $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%");
    })
    ->where('project_id', $projectId)
    ->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%")
    ->get();
return $result;
```

Comment: you need () after workPackage for relation not object,
$this->workPackage()->whereHas

Comment: @OMR how do you know that? The original question doesn't have it and we don't know the context in which `$this` exists

Comment: @STA when I use whereHas its return empty data, when I use with then at least getting WorkPackage table data with matching records. And one problem is I am not able to use $title in $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%"); error getting undefined title.

Comment: @Tushar whats about `$this->workPackage()->whereHas` ?

Comment: @STA $this-> workPackage will work only workPackage() this will not work ,because I have created object for it

Comment: @TusharKumbhar you might need to use `work_items.title` in both cases if the same name of column exists in both tables because `whereHas` is converted into a `SELECT * FROM work_packages WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM work_items WHERE title LIKE ?) AND title like ?` so you'd get a conflict in this case

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me. Thanks to everyone for help to get right answer.

```
   $result['data'] = $this->workPackage->with(['work_items' => function ($q) use ($title) {
        $q->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%");
    }])
        ->where('project_id', $projectId)
        ->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%")
        ->get();
    return $result;
```

Comment: You just add `use ($title)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be solved with join method:

```
$result = $this->workPackage
->join('work_items', 'work_packages.id', '=', 'work_items.package_id')
->where('work_items.title', 'LIKE', '%{$term}%')
->orWhere('work_packages.title', 'LIKE', '%{$term}%')
->get();
```